# AdMobBanner works in Android Emulator but not in an apk-build ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, admob, jsx, expo

My Android Emulator shows a real adUnit (created Unit ID from Google adMob) on the screen.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpMxJ.png)

When I build the apk, my apk on my real device don't show it and I get this Error: "ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL"

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlTBq.png)

public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
Constant Value: 3
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

---

```
bannerError = (error) => {
    alert(error);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <AdMobBanner
        style= {stylesAdMobBanner.adMobContainer}
        bannerSize={this.props.bannerSize}
        adUnitID={this.props.adUnitID}
        onAdFailedToLoad={error => this.bannerError(error)}
        onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={error => this.bannerError(error)}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

---

What do I have to do, that I get acces to the inventory of the ads? Is here any configuration on Google adMob for the adUnits necessary?

Comment: Can you see the settings for your advertisement? ID values

Comment: In Google AdMob I can see that I had 125 requests from my ad's to the advertisement network until now.

Comment: Did you put the test ID value into your device value?

Comment: Could you show me the ads code?

Comment: <AdMobBannerTemplate adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" bannerSize="largeBanner"/> this is my call of the component. I don't work with the testID. The adUnitID is the test id. Here I work with my own which I created in Google AdMob.

Comment: Isn't this.props.adUnitID value not delivered properly? Does the same happen if I input and insert actual data values?

Comment: Enter a testID value for the device to perform.  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=ko

Comment: It delivers there as it should. I wirte it in Text and the value is the one it should be.

Comment: What do you mean by actual data values?

Comment: The original adMobBanner (from Google adMob) works in my Emulator without any problems. More important is, why it's not working on real devices...

Comment: This refers to the value you created, not the value you passed.

Comment: I added a example adUnitID like 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111' and it works as it should. I get a test Banner like it is shown in many tutorials.

Comment: UPDATE: The programming code, which I debug with a android Emulator shows the adBanner. When I build a apk file of my whole code and install it there, it don't shows as my real android smartphone the same error!

Comment: pls look in my original Post, I added two pictures like it works without apk and with a builded .apk it doesn't work!

Comment: ERROR_NOFILL is The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Comment: Currently, ads are exposed after the app is distributed to PlayStore. Therefore, when under development, a test advertisement should be placed to ensure that the ad is well-known and the normal advertising ID value should be added in the released APK to ensure that the ad is well exposed.

Comment: So the adMobBanner of the "real" UnitID will only be seen, when the App is placed into the Google Play Store?

Comment: Or better: The adUnitID's which are already created are only provided with ads by Google, when the app is in the Google Play Store?

Comment: If you're actually using UnitID, you can check it with release apk and IPA, even if you don't upload it in the app store.

Comment: It works as it should now! :) There was no problem in my code. The release channel is now "production", that seems to make the difference :)

Comment: Yes, the error is saying there is no problem with your code. It is simply the result of the difference in UnitID. If my answer was helpful, would you choose my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`ERROR_NOFILL` is The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory

Currently, ads are exposed after the app is distributed to PlayStore. Therefore, when under development, a test advertisement should be placed to ensure that the ad is well-known and the normal advertising ID value should be added in the released APK to ensure that the ad is well exposed.

You try use the actual advertising unitID.

If you're actually using UnitID, you can check it with release apk and IPA, even if you don't upload it in the app store.